# Question about migration techniques on a production db that seem confusing

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I use C#, .NET and EF Core/SQL for the data layer.

I've read a book on EF Core and one on TSQL and now I'm confused about some aspects of the migration techniques on a production system.

My questions are:

- I've read about the fact that you can just use `script migration -idempotent` to get a new/the applicable migration script, taking into account what migration was the last one in the `EFMigration_History` table. In the book it says you NEED a tool such as `DbUp` or RedGate's `flyaway` in order to run this script. Can't you just use MSSMS to do it ? Or the VS SQL Server Explorer's `New Query` ?
- There was also a technique, considered an easy one, where you would create a console app within your solution, this console app would just have `context.Database.Migrate` in it so that it could run whenever you call it and apply the new migration to a stopped app or a running app with some other tweaks, which is very confusing because maybe I'm not understanding this at all, but when the code is live you can't call/run a solution's project and have an impact on the production system right ? And if so do you have an idea what this technique really is ?
- Do you recommend using SQL scripts to build migrations ? The use of a SQL database comparison tool to produce migration form the current database schema to the desired database schema, it seems like you need good knowledge of SQL but I'm not too bad.

I'd like to know what you recommend to understand what's my best bet at not breaking my production system by planning ahead of time and making sure I understand what to do before I have to re do everything.

Comment: I have tried both, first we had a setup where we would run the SQL scripts and do schema comparisons manually etc. Then we upgraded our code to be code first instead of the DB first with EF. Then to run the migrations we created a console app utility (as we have a multi-tenant architecture where each company has their own DB). This was the best decision ever. We now do all our Dev, add migrations etc. Then when releasing a new version to Prod we just run the Console Utility (can be run in CI pipeline) and push the new code.

Comment: I see, does that mean that I should start learning about CI in order to understand and/or be able to do this right ? Or it's just your decision to do it through a CI pipeline and just knowing how to call the Console Utility in any way would be enough for me ?

Comment: @CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt - sorry for my mistake. Posted my comment against the wrong question. Removed it.

Comment: @DawoodAwan also could you direct me to a source on how to do this right ? Or post an answer on how you did it ? It's the first time I do it and I'm trying to find resources online on how to do it but I can't seem to be able to find a tutorial on how to do this right.

Comment: @CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt no currently we don't use CI for this, we just run the utility manually when releasing a new version after tested in staging/QA. I'll post the code to run the migrations, you should be able build on top of it. It's basically just calling the Migrate() on the DbContext and it does the rest. If you want to revert on any errors you will have to look up how do to that.

Comment: Great, thank you Dawood, could you also just show me how you manually call the utility ? I'm also confused on how you do that and how it has an impact on the production database.

Comment: It's a console application, just double click the .exe file - it will build the connection strings based on appsettings.json .  it will run all the migrations one-by-one as it does on Dev machine..... It's basically similar to running`dotnet ef database update` - but because we need more control in Prod and the fact we have 100s of DBs (to build the connection strings) we just use this Util. But not more different than running `dotnet ef database update` locally....

Comment: I see, and does the utility use `appsettings.Production.json` by default or do you have to use some type of parameters to let it know you don't want to update the dev db ? Since I know Azure overrides the connection string to be the prod one and then just uses it but since you run the local .exe is there a way to let it know ? I'm asking that because I read something I think that says call both your dev connection string and prod conn string the same and the environment will make the choice on which to choose at runtime. It sounds very amateurish but this being the first time :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to run the migrations, which will output the Migrations run with success and errors. You should be able to build on top of it.

```
protected virtual void RunMigrations(String connectionString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n ---- Running migrations for [{connectionString}]");

            var dbContext = GetDbContext(connectionString);

            var pendingMigrations = dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations();
            var latestMigration = pendingMigrations.OrderByDescending(t => t).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                if (pendingMigrations.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Running migrations \n - {0}", String.Join("\n - ", pendingMigrations));

                    dbContext.Database.Migrate();

                    Console.WriteLine("Migrations completed...........................");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No pending migrations.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                var successfulMigrations = pendingMigrations.Intersect(dbContext.Database.GetAppliedMigrations());
                var unsuccessfulMigrations = pendingMigrations.Except(successfulMigrations);

                if (unsuccessfulMigrations.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to apply the following migrations \n - {0}", String.Join("\n -", unsuccessfulMigrations));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Dawood ! One more thing, you also just show me how you manually call the utility ? I'm also confused on how you do that and how it has an impact on the production database.

Comment: answered above..

Comment: This is just one way, there are different approaches . Each project requires different stratergies. This one works for us. But in the official docs there are other ways which will work for other projects. You will just have to do some R&D and find the best way for your project. But back to my original comment, don't manually compare schemas --> generate SQL script --> then run in Prod. Use an automated tool, like EF Migrate, it is quite good and saves loads of time. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)